# relatedQuery.setDefinitionExpression not working jsapi arcgis

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to relate two tables STATION and TEMP this my code :

```
var relatedQuery = new RelationshipQuery();
relatedQuery.objectIds = [graphic.attributes.objectid];
relatedQuery.relationshipId = 0;
relatedQuery.outFields = ["*"];
relatedQuery.setDefinitionExpression = "CAST(date_ AS CHAR(8)) LIKE '201201%'";
console.log(relatedQuery);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
station_lyr.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, function(relatedRecords){
for(var oid in relatedRecords) {
console.log("related :" + relatedRecords[oid]);
}}
```

my problem is that the properties setDefinitionExpression not working i have always features: Array[366] ( records : 366 )

but when i used this parametres in REST API INTERFACE i find records : 31 [image]

Comment: the easiest and most helpful thing to do would be to snoop the web traffic spawned by your own application to compare the request that is made from your app with the request you'd like to be making to see how they differ.